# Trying to append an input number in a list function is returning none

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to return a list of numbers input by the user.

I have tried to insert an empty list and then using the `.append` function to append the input value to the list.

```
def ask_a_number():
    trials = []
    playernumber = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    trials = trials.append(playernumber)
    return playernumber, trials
ask_a_number()
```

Lets say I want to input 5. 
So I want the function to return 5 and also a list `trials = [5]`.
Next time when I input 10, the function should return `trials = [5,10]`.

Comment: append does not return anything, it modifies the list inplace. Try changing to: `trials.append(playernumber)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append()` doesn't return anything. It is designed to do in-place modification. So just do the following:

```
def ask_a_number(trials=None):
    trials = trials or []
    playernumber = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    trials.append(playernumber)
    return playernumber, trials
ask_a_number()
```

I've also added a default value for `trials` so that if you want to do this in a loop, you can like so:

```
trials = []

for i in range(6):
    player, trials = ask_a_number(trials)
```

Comment: Got it.. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
trials = trials.append(playernumber)
```

to

```
trials.append(playernumber)
```

Since `list.append` returns `None` (it alters the state of `trials` instead) and you reassign its return value to `trials`, you get `None` in your returned tuple.

Comment: Got it. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 def ask_a_number():
       trials = []
       while True:
           playernumber = int(input('Guess a number: '))
           trials.append(playernumber)
           if playernumber==0:
             break
       print(playernumber, trials)
       return 
 ask_a_number()
```

Comment: Please add some brief that what you did special.

Comment: i think you must calm down